# Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: 12.04, gtk

Today I installed:

1. Ubuntu 12.04
2. Oracle JDK 7 and 8
3. IntelliJ 11.1.4

I setup my JAVA_HOME path to point to JDK 7.

When I run IntelliJ I get this message:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Is this a problem or can I over look this?

Comment: This is a fairly generic message.  And a lot has changed since this question was posted.  No more 32-bit versions are considered modern, for one.  I posted the simple answer below that works in July 2017.  Simply install that module.  That's it.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I fixed this by installing the module:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Or if it's already installed and you still get the error:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

Comment: I have libcanberra-gtk-module already installed and it is still showing the error. any ideas?

Comment: @JimFord  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed

Comment: I know this answer was written 4 years and 9 months ago, but here in July 2017 there are no more modern i386 versions being offered.  They have become specialty items, mostly for maintenance purposes.  So I posted a similar answer below, omitting the confusion about which command will work for you.

Comment: Used for LibreOffice in a docker container

Comment: Used first instruction without the :386 for successfully installing Gog's Neverwinter Nights Enhanced Edition in Fall 2021 without getting the "Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"" error message on a "fresh" Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS install, with applied updates. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

This question is 4 years and 8 months old.  It is now July 2017.

On a **Raspberry Pi 3B running Raspbian Jessie** and **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** I was getting this error.

> Failed to load module “canberra-gtk-module”

It is fairly generic.

**The good news is that the fix is easy.**  Simply enter:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

installed some stuff...

Then it never showed up again.

Comment: Cross-posted this at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70048/how-to-stop-raspbian-leafpad-from-leaving-behind-the-message-failed-to-load-mod

Comment: Is this not the same answer as the original answer from the OP? The command appears to be identical.

Answer (score 9):

happened with a qt5 application using gtk theme on Ubuntu MATE

```
$ ./my-application
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "topmenu-gtk-module"
```

let's locate the libs

```
$ locate libcanberra-gtk-module.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
```

setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH solves the issue

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./my-application
```

or unset the GTK_MODULES environment variable

```
$ unset GTK_MODULES; ./my-application
```