# Failed to load module “canberra-gtk-module” .... but already installed

Tags: gtk

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

but I already have the `libcanberra-gtk-module`  and `libcanberra-gtk3-module` installed.
(i.e. I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208431/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module), but it is already installed.)

This happens for instance, when I run `ipython --pylab`

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 - raring.

Answer (score 506):

install gtk and gtk3 module should solve it.

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

Comment: For me `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module` worked fine

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This works for Android Studio

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18

Comment: worked for me too, ubuntu 18.04.1. Installing pidgin from terminal was the only way to show office-communicator protocol (for Lync) and I stumbled on this same problem but solved with the above and now OCommunicator shows. Thanks!

Comment: This worked, but what is canberra-gtk-module anyways?

Comment: After an update of Spotify client, I had to reinstall these packages. Now it works like a charm!

Comment: didn't worked for me. Using octave, and error is happening.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: This worked for me. The error happened whenever I opened gVim. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 (bionic).

Comment: sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module worked for Android Studio on Debian 10

Comment: for me it was `libcanberra-gtk0`

Comment: sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev fixed all the issues for me.

Comment: worked for ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @SoichiHayashi according to https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libcanberra-gtk-module, "canberra-gtk-module translates GTK+ widgets signals to event sounds. A GtkModule which will automatically hook into all kinds of events inside a GTK+ program and generate sound events from them. "

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: This solution works for me, but only after a reboot, which is a strange necessity in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 116):

This problem may occur on a 64-bit machine when one installs 32-bit software that requires canberra-gtk-module. acroread, for example, can cause this problem. In this case, the solution is to install the 32-bit version:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

One should leave the 64-bit version as well as it is necessary for 64-bit programs which attempt to use it.

Comment: I have a 32-bit system so I don't think this applies.  Any other ideas?  It's the Copy.com client that throws the error.

Comment: It fixed my 32-bits Firefox on Ubuntu 64-bits.

Comment: This did not help for me. I also tried `sudo apt-get remove libcanberra-gtk-module` before `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386`, still does not work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did not solve this error with Polar Bookshelf on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Doesn't work for me too

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 40):

**WARNING:** User Paparazio reported that this command removed a lot more software than he was expecting. See [his question](https://askubuntu.com/q/918881/301745) for details. –
wjandrea
Jun 8 2017 at 20:29

---

I had the same problem and solve it with the solution given in this [launchpad issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libcanberra/+bug/689434).

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: **WARNING**: User Paparazio reported that this command removed a lot more software than he was expecting. See [his question](https://askubuntu.com/q/918881/301745) for details.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Worked for me, ending in installation of libcanberra-gtk0. Seeing the warning from Paparazio reported by wjandrea, I first check with '-s' as an argument to apt-get : `apt-get install -s --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module` then the line given above

Comment: worked for me Ubuntu 19.10. Thanks.

Comment: I get `qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig (8 8 8 0)`

Answer (score 8):

Maybe too much but this solved my problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*
```

Comment: terrible idea and didn't even get rid of that error when I tried it.

Comment: Please, use apt-get with wildcards with caution - or better: don't use wildcards. This often leads to unexpected results that are not easy to fix for people without in-depth experience of the package management system.

Comment: This answer solved my problem! I'm a little nervous now that I read the comments after the fact but so far so good... thanks @Mona