# Problems with “canberra-gtk-module,” followed answer, banged my head on the desk

Tags: gtk, aptitude

I just started using Ubuntu. I was trying to get Adobe Reader to work and got stuck on the seemingly common problem `Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`. I tried several of the suggestions on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/342202/692495), including the one described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/732066/692495):

```
sudo aptitude reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module
```

The problem was not solved, but that command removed a WHOLE BUNCH of stuff from my machine that I now have to reinstall, including CUDA, Caffe, and others that I didn't get the chance to note down while the whole thing was happening.

Following [this answer on Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17008/692495), I am posting this information here because I don't have the reputation to comment under the original answer, but I want to warn others against using that command without knowing what they are getting themselves into.

In addition, are there policies I can use in the future to try stuff out without messing my system up as much as I did this time?

Comment: If your question is *"What are some policies I can use in the future to try stuff out without messing my system up as much as I did this time? "* then IMHO your title should reflect that

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver, you do have a point. The post is a bit of a hybrid, because part of it is to ask that, part of it is to warn others who may not realize the consequences of that command. For now I will edit the question to clarify that there are two aspects to it.

Comment: I've added [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed/732066#comment1459206_732066) on the relevant answer as a warning.