# Failed to load module appmenu-gtk-module + canberra-gtk-module

Tags: gtk, gtk3

[image: terminal picture]

I have already tried :

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-modul
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU. Could cut and paste the relevant parts of the screenshot?  This is much clearer and uses less ressources.  Thanks.

Comment: it's "module" not modul

Answer (score 41):

To install the GTK2 and GTK3 modules:

```
sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module
```

Comment: When running PyQt5 apps on Ubuntu 19.10 I was getting annoying `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"` warnings.  This answer solved it.

Comment: Same for me in Ubuntu 19.10. To fix `Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"` problem just run :
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module` 
which I found in https://askubuntu.com/a/732066/534825.

Comment: This didn't do it for my problem with tusk which displays this when invoked.