# dconf-editor shortcuts don't work

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, shortcuts, dconf

I'm used to work with 6 workspaces. I can assign shortcuts to change to anyone of them trough the settings menu > shortcuts, and it works. But it only offers the "option" to stablish shortcuts for workspaces 1 to 4.

I have tried running the `dconf-editor` and change `org/gnome/desktop/vm/keybindings` and add there a new shortcut for workspaces 5 and 6. Like, say `['<Super>F5']` and F6 or anyother combination...

First, I though I might be writting it wrong, so I copied others I saw there, just altering them a bit they didn't match anyother).

But no mutter wich combination I choose, I can't make it work. This is really anoying. Can anyone see my error here?

(I did try running dconf-editor with sudo)

EDIT: sorry, I'm in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, GNOME version 3.36.1, with X11 window system.

EDIT 2: Yes, in Gnome Tweaks `static workspaces` is enabled and the number set to 6. I wouldn't be expecting a shortcut to a non existing workspace to work (maybe just for the immediate next, one at a time. But that is not the case).

I have 6 static, for the first 4 the gnome standard shortcut settings lets me change the keys, and they work fine. But the dconf for the extra 5th and 6th don't seem to do anything).

EDIT 3: I saw a new error today, that I describe in the answer below, about the module `appmenu-gtk-module`. That seemed to be the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why after turning off the PC yesterday and trying today once again to edit dconf-editor I saw an error on the terminal that didn't show before:

`Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"`

(I did saw another error many times: *WARNING **: night-light-monitor.vala:149: Impossible to get cached property from proxy, night-light mode disabled*, but that one I think is not related at all)

I searched for the gtk-module error and come up with [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1093707/1074228):

- Install the GTK2 and GTK3 modules:

  `sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module`

Then run again the `dconf-editor` and not only the changes did apply correctly, but I also saw there the current shortcuts for the workspaces 1 to 4, wich previously didn't show on the dconf-editor.

Thanks for the help everybody.