# 20.04 LTS -- unity or appmenu?

Tags: apt, unity, gtk

20.04 LTS current.  I keep seeing the diagnostic `Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"`

[Failed to load module appmenu-gtk-module + canberra-gtk-module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074926/failed-to-load-module-appmenu-gtk-module-canberra-gtk-module) suggests `sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module`

However, this command seems to require that two unity packages will be removed; thus, there seems to be a conflict between the two sets of packages.

```
`The following packages will be REMOVED:
  unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module`
```

is the output from the `sudo apt install` command.  Which is the correct set to remain:  the appmenu or the unity "versions"?

Comment: Provide details about your system, your desktop environment and the history of it (is this an updated system? Do you use Unity desktop or have you used it before, etc.)

Comment: From neofetch:  OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: HP ZBook 15 G2 A3009DD10203 
Kernel: 5.8.0-41-generic 
Uptime: 13 mins 
Packages: 3557 (dpkg), 13 (snap)   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: MATE 
WM: Metacity (Marco) 
WM Theme: TraditionalOk 
Theme: TraditionalOk [GTK2/3] 
 Icons: mate [GTK2/3] 
Terminal Font: Monospace 10 
CPU: Intel i7-4810MQ (8) @ 3.800GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA Quadro K1100M 
Memory: 4274MiB / 15928MiB 
Terminal: mate-terminal   Note that I run KDE and Gnome applications under MATE, and I have a number of file managers, including Sunflower

Comment: @vanadium  There has been no response to the above for four days.  I do not want to "break" a working system.  Given the system configuration above, does it need Unity?  Is Unity a "hidden" dependency for other applications?  Is there a way to discover this other than to proceed and possibly "break" applications?  If applications are "broken", will simply reversing the install and remove apt commands above restore the system, or will there other dependencies removed or configuration files deleted, changed, or corrupted (a change that is inconsistent or unstable with the system as to be run)?