# Multiple problems with C++ IDEs. Netbeans not working. Codeblocks Indenting not working

Tags: ide

Probably going to be deleted but I can't post 3 questions for this...

1. Netbeans not working:
   [image: Netbeans Screen Shoot With Output Error]

Ok, so I don't know what is happening, but I can't use NetBeans at all. Anything I would do, the program says *RUN FINISHED* and I won't work... I can't even input and output an integer...

[image: Input/Output a variable]

The second problem with NetBeans, you can already see in the first picture, the methods, and some words are underlined with red for **no reason**, the code works perfectly on code blocks!

2. Codeblocks indenting is working like crap if I write:

   int main()

and then type { and press enter I get this: [image: this]

And I have to press one more time to enter for the second bracket to go down and press <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to go back on the line and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, this is horrible.

If you know any IDE I can use, without spending an hour to install them, that would be great, and maybe looks decent and not so **2002** like some things I have experienced since I got Linux...

Comment: KDevelop en QtCreator are probably the most modern looking and they do not come with the java bloat of netbeans and eclipse.

Comment: Ok, I will try KDevelop, and QtCreator is for, well, QtC++ and I am doing only console applications (I mean algorithms)!

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse-cdt package contains Eclipse features and plugins that are useful for C and C++ development. To install eclipse-cdt in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install eclipse-cdt
```

fos4cdt is an Eclipse plugin to format C/C++ source files on any save action. When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or click the *Save* button, the plugin formats saved files automatically. You can enable/disable auto formatting by a preference page and using shortcut keys.

fos4cdt can be installed in Eclipse from the Eclipse Marketplace. To open an Eclipse Marketplace window in Eclipse select *Help* -> *Eclipse Marketplace* -> search for fos4cdt -> click *Browse for more solutions* link to open http://marketplace.eclipse.org in a new tab in Eclipse -> click the house icon underneath the Eclipse icon to go to the fos4cdt download page.

[image]
<sup>**before code formatting**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**after code formatting**</sup>

I tested the fos4cdt Eclipse plugin against UniversalIndentGUI from the Ubuntu repositories. fos4cdt does a better job of pretty formatting code than UniversalIndentGUI. UniversalIndentGUI indents code logically, but except for fixing the indentations it does not do any other pretty formatting.

Comment: I have tried it... It won't run, I get this error message:
_An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/skrefi/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1549474619434.log_

And first this in the CLI: _Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
_

Decided, this time, to google that (actually before posting this I didn't use CLI and didn't see that error) and I reached this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed

It is still not working, I can't even run Eclipse...

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Version: Photon Release (4.8.0) in Ubuntu 18.04. You are using Eclipse Juno 3.8.

Comment: And how do I get Photon Release?

Comment: [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-12/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers) is harder to learn to use than Code::Blocks and more full-featured.