# Cannot install Chromium browser in 20.04 Focal

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, snap, chromium

I tried installing Chromium from the Software GUI. Nothing happened and `top` showed no `chromium` process running. I tried launching `chromium-browser` from the CL and got a `Gtk Message` error: `Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed) and ran

`sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module`

This did not solve the problem, and now the error message was (and remains):

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

and

`[ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(384)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.`

The latter error sometimes occurs before `Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)` and sometimes after. It doesn't give me back my command prompt but puts me on an unadorned new line (no `>` or other sign of being inside a program). I have no idea what's going on, so I type `^C` to escape.

So I uninstalled Chromium with the Software GUI (which uses snap). I tried installing with apt, got the same error, and uninstalled. Because I learned that apt just calls for a snap install, I used `snap install chromium` and have installed, removed it, restarted and reinstalled.

I revisited the answer linked above and ran

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

which installed nine 32-bit packages. It did not solve the problem.

I'm out of ideas. I am still pretty new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Uninstall everything that you installed. Undo everything that you did. Then, when it's all cleaned up, try: `sudo snap install chromium`. The Chromium packagers only release snaps.

Comment: To be fair to Rob, he does state he tried using the snap.

Comment: With respect, "when it's all cleaned up" is not a helpful guideline, esp. to a new user.

Comment: @RobCollins I have the same issue. Nothing on the thread you linked worked for me, either. Have you had any luck? I've tried installing with both `apt` and `snap`, neither work.