# How do I fix the new snap release of Chromium so that it launches?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, snap, chromium, gtk

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Focal Fossa
Chromium 87.0.4280.66

**Problem**

I recently upgraded Ubuntu 18.04.5 to 20.04.1 in place, i.e. Software Upgrader wrote the new version of all app files over their predecessors. During the upgrade, the .deb version of Chromium was removed and replaced by the snap version 87.0.4280.66.

However, when I double-click the Chromium icon, it starts to launch and Chromium Web Browser appears in the desktop Activities bar, but then disappears. I tried removing and reinstalling the snap with Ubuntu Software and Synaptic, but Chromium continued the same behaviour.

***canberra-gtk-module*** **warnings**

When launched from the Terminal, this is what happens:

```
~$ which chromium
/snap/bin/chromium
~$ echo $PATH
/opt/gutenprint/sbin:/opt/gutenprint/bin:/opt/GitHub Desktop:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/bin/node:  

~$ chromium  

(chrome:40586): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:46:29.670: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1565:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(chrome:40586): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:46:29.674: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3615:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(chrome:40586): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:46:29.675: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4077:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
Gtk-Message: 19:46:29.706: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 19:46:29.707: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[40722:40722:1130/194629.798673:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
~$
```

I tried installing the `libcanberra-gtk-module`*, `libcanberra-gtk3-module`, `libcanberra-gtk3-0`, `libcanberra-gtk-module:i386`, `libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386`, and `libcanberra-gtk3-0:i386` as suggested in the response, but the latest versions were already installed. Chromium still won't launch.

This issue dates back to Ubuntu 11 -- see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libcanberra/+bug/689434

**Checked snap version of Chromium installed**

Tried manually installing Chromium snap:

```
~$ sudo snap install chromium
snap "chromium" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
~$ sudo snap refresh
All snaps up to date.
```

**Where to?**

Running out of ideas. New ideas welcome!

---

* Canberra is the capital city of Australia. What has that got to do with this package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load module “canberra-gtk-module” .... but already installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed)

Comment: Failed to load module “canberra-gtk-module” .... but already installed – Mark Kirby does not apply. Latest 64- and 32-bit versions already installed.

Answer (score 0):

This error will go away if you login and logout. Initially I tried solving the `Theme parsing error: gtk.css:xxxx:xx: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name` error by opening the System Monitor application and killing all Chromium processes one at a time. This caused the Ubuntu 20.04 desktop to be replaced by a black screen. I pressed the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> keyboard combination to exit from the black screen to a virtual console. When I logged back in to Ubuntu from the virtual console the usual Ubuntu login screen appeared automatically and I was able to log in. After logging back in Chromium resumed working again as usual.