# Where are 32 bit libraries installed?

Tags: gtk

I have canberra-gtk-module 64 and 32 bit versions installed, but the app I'm running can't find it.

I find the 64 bit version here:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk3-module.so

but there is no corresponding 32 bit folder.

Comment: On which version of Ubuntu you are on? How did you install that GTK module? Which app isn't finding it? What error message are you getting?  Please [edit] to include these details.

Comment: See this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/349672/558158 Not sure if this still works: 32 bit support was dropped to some extent

Answer (score 2):

The *`libcanberra-gtk3-module.so`* library for 32-bit will be installed to
`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk3-module.so`
by
`sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386`

See [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=impish&arch=i386&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libcanberra-gtk3-module.so) for details.