# I can't use firefox on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on Board Intel DG31PR core 2 Duo 3.00 GHz

Tags: firefox

after installing it, run firefox and no window opens, however in the system monitor I see firefox running, the same thing happens with chrome and opera, ¿what can i do, could someone help me? my computer has 2 cores 4G memory and more than 250G free disk

Comment: Please provide all details in your question text (*depending on browser setup, details in title may not be readable when reading your question, which doesn't mention what release you're using*).  If you install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, `firefox` is installed by default and doesn't need installation, are you using the desktop release?  What screen resolution are you using? (in QA I've used resolutions down to 1024x800 without issue)3

Comment: As you report several browsers have this issue it is not a Firefox problem. More details are needed.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, the problem is that none of the browsers (firefox, chrome, Opera) work on Ubuntu 22.04.1. therefore I don't have internet access since Ubuntu 22.04.1. This Ubuntu 22.0.4.1 install it on on Board Intel DG31PR core 2 Duo 3.00 GHz which has 2 core processor, 4G memory and more than 250G free disk space. the resolution of Ubuntu with which I configure Ubuntu is 1024 x 768, I have changed it to other resolutions and still the browsers do not work.

Comment: I am using the desktop version of Ubuntu 22.04.1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just upgraded to 22.04 or reinstall the ubuntu-desktop. 
You can use `snap list` to check out the information in the last column "Notes".

1. If any of your core/core22/core20/core18 show "broken", then
   `sudo snap remove core(choose all broken)` 
   `sudo sanp install core(same)`
2. Or firefox shows "disable",then 
   `sudo apt enable firefox` and the type `firefox` in terminal. 
   Maybe it will pop out errors like `failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"` 
   https://askubuntu.com/a/208436/1630689 will help you with this.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your collaboration, I tried these options but I can't get firefox to work

Comment: Actually, Snap is a terrible package manager. I recommend that you remove all packages installed by snap and snap itself (remember to disable re-installation by itself). And if the question still bothers you, you can install Firefox by following official instructions via zip.