# Inkscape file paths are relative to home folder

Tags: snap, inkscape

I have installed `inkscape` on Ubuntu `20.04`.

The version of `inkscape` is

```
inkscape -V

Gtk-Message: 20:38:33.029: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 20:38:33.030: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Inkscape 1.3.2 (9e3d6414e7, 2024-01-14, custom)
```

I want to convert an `svg` file into `png`.
The problem is when I give a relative path to inkscape, instead of interpreting the path as relative, it is interpreted as relative to the home folder:

```
inkscape ./mydrawing.svg --export-area-drawing --batch-process --export-type=pdf
```

gives

```
Gtk-Message: 20:42:58.054: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 20:42:58.056: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:175089): WARNING **: 20:42:58.388: Can't open file: /home/myhome/mydrawing.svg (doesn't exist)

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:175089): WARNING **: 20:42:58.388: Can't open file: /home/myhome/mydrawing.svg (doesn't exist)
ink_file_open: '/home/myhome/mydrawing.svg' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /home/myhome/mydrawing.svg
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!
```

hence, it cannot open the file.

Regarding to the error:

> Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

I tried these solution

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
sudo apt install -s --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

as well as all solutions provided at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208431/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module) question and none of them worked. I am not sure if this warning is causing this problem.

---

```
type -a inkscape ; ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d
inkscape is /snap/bin/inkscape
total 0
```

Version 1.3.1 is a stable version:

```
snap list inkscape  --all
Name      Version                           Rev    Tracking       Publisher  Notes
inkscape  1.3.2-9e3d6414e7-2024-01-14-cust  10563  latest/stable  inkscape✓  disabled
inkscape  1.3.1-9b9bdc1480-2023-11-25-cust  10555  latest/stable  inkscape✓  -
```

I also tried:

```
snap refresh --stable inkscape
inkscape 1.3.1-9b9bdc1480-2023-11-25-cust from Inkscape Project (inkscape✓) refreshed
```

Comment: Inkscape 1.3.2 is not a version shipped with Ubuntu. I'm on 23.10 and even 24.04 only has 1.2.2. Please remove all third-party PPAs and reinstall Inkscape. The `inkscape ./mydrawing.svg --export-area-drawing --batch-process --export-type=pdf` works fine on 1.2.2

Comment: @DanielT, thanks. Is there any command to remove all third party PPAs? and is there any risk involved?

Comment: @DanielT, the problem is that I do not know what PPA is causing this. Here is my log: https://paste.mozilla.org/84RYkqfZ . I more suspect to snap vs apt.

Comment: @DanielT, I did

Comment: Oh you're using the snap. snap tends to break a lot of things related to filesystem access. `sudo snap remove --purge inkscape ; sudo apt install inkscape` like https://askubuntu.com/q/1414173/1004020

Comment: @DanielT, the apt version is too old (`Inkscape 0.92.5`). It does create empty PDF file too. How can I have the `1.2.2` version?

Comment: You can see which Inkscape version is available on which Ubuntu release at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=inkscape . To avoid further bugs like the one you encountered, just upgrade the Ubuntu release to get a version of Inkscape that is tested to work together

Comment: For ubuntu 20.04, the version is too old (0.92.5) and for ubuntu 23.10, the version is good (1.2.2). The problem is that if I have files created with new ubuntu, I cannot convert them using the older laptop. Even the funnier part is that I followed the advise of [inkscape website](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.2.2/gnulinux/ubuntu/ppa/dl/) to install version 1.2.2 but it installs version 1.2.3

Comment: Just upgrade to 22.04. Or you could file a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape and wait

Comment: I am not even sure if downgrading to version 1.2.2 will fix the problem. But I know `Inkscape-091e20e-x86_64.AppImage` is working fine for me.

Comment: Please post that as an answer. This might even be a limitation of snap stuff in general, so AppImage would work

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `Daniel T`.

This is an issue on inkscape `1.3.1`.

I submitted a [bug report](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/9998) for now. I might not have time to follow it up.

For now, I use the `Inkscape-091e20e-x86_64.AppImage` (version 1.3.2) at [inkscape.org](https://inkscape.org/release/all/gnulinux/appimage/) and it works fine.